# How was Sara John Diggle's gender changed in the alternate timeline?

Tags: arrowverse, the-flash, arrow

In s03e01 of The Flash, Barry has created an alternate timeline wherein he is happily living with his parents.

When he returns back to the original timeline (one in which his mother is dead), he tells his friends about their doppelgangers from that alternate timeline.

He tells John Diggle (from Arrow) that he had baby John in the alternate timeline, and not baby Sara (as in the current timeline).

Now, we know that everyone has a doppelganger in every different timeline ever created. In this specific case, how come the baby's gender got changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time changed from the moment Barry changed, forward. Everything pre-normas death is the same.  Anyone already alive continued to be alive. But time progresses from there, and every thing could change based on the new decisions made. The further away from the event the more things change.

In this timeline, it's likely that John and the baby mother made different decisions,  and conceived at a different time. And random chance that a different sperm won the race. Each sperm has different DNA payloads. As does each egg. As a baby is essentially the result of multiple random mutations of the combined sperm and egg,  any change in the timeline could change the result.

**Since Sara was borne in October and John in November, John Sr. And Lyla had to have conceived at a different point in time.**

Look at how Barry changed the timeline in season 2. Hartley went from psycho rogue to occasionally helpful friend. Any change in the past has ripple effects.

Comment: Agreed about the change in behavior of a person, after all doppelganger is an evil twin. But in no other case did we see a gender change of a person!

Comment: @cincout a doppelganger doesn't imply evil. Earth 2 Barry isn't evil for example. Many aren't. But like I said, Sara and John are the only ones who were born AFTER the day Nora died. They are the only ones that could change gender, based on the events after Nora not dying.

Comment: Makes sense about the kids being born after Nora's death.